# When in click a radio button, it scroll to the top. How to prenvent that?

Tags: html, events, input

I've got a formular with radio input. when the input is on the bottom of the page and I select one, it scrolls to the top of the page.

How can this be?
How to prevent that?

I'm using d3, and formatting the radio to look like button.

Comment: That isn't normal behaviour for a radio button, but since you haven't provided [a test case](http://sscce.org/) we can't tell why your radio button is behaving abnormally.

Comment: You should show some code

Comment: Does the link in the browser address bar change after you clicked the radio button?

Comment: Do you have some jquery attached behavior to this button ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it : to hide the round selector, the css use a trick :

```
position:absolute;
top:-10px;
```

when i click on the label, the browser scroll to the top, where the round selector is.

Answer (score 1):

It might need a parent element that is not positioned with "static".
I think your radio button positioned on top of scroll

Answer (score 0):

To hide the round selector there would be css like this

```
.radio:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
```

It will scroll the page to top. Please change top attribute with left

```
.radio:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
```